# laravel 5 development.ERROR

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im getting this error randomly,i search it and it seems that this happens if you havent set an app key,the problem is i had set it from the start.The problem usually happens when i make multiple $http  calls from my app it never happens from postman.

error:

```
[2015-10-12 16:36:11] development.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in C:\xampp2\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:29 Stack trace:
0 C:\xampp2\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(733): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
1 C:\xampp2\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(626): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
2 C:\xampp2\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
3 C:\xampp2\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(837): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\Cont...')
4 C:\xampp2\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(800): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
5 C:\xampp2\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(771): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
6 C:\xampp2\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(626): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Http\Middle...', Array)
7 C:\xampp2\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\Http\Middle...', Array)
8 C:\xampp2\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\Http\Middle...')
9 C:\xampp2\htdocs\public\index.php(58): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Http\Response))
10 {main}
```

update:
ok i checked it a little more and if change the app.php

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'someRandomString')
```

with my key

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'My key')
```

im getting error 404 not found on the route.I think that at some point randomly fails to read the env key.It may be a problem with my resources im developing on my computer i will upload it to a server and check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i solved it the problem was my computer resources was not enough to make multiple calls after i upload to server everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should change it in your `.env` file, when you change the `someRandomString` in the `env()` call all you're doing is telling Laravel to use that as a default if it can't find the real app key. So Laravel is probably finding an incorrect app key and never gets to your default.

If you don't have a `.env` file (but you probably do, since your default failed), you should have a `.env.example` file that you can rename. Then you can do `php artisan key:generate` to generate and set it automatically.

If it still doesn't work after doing that, you have some other problem unrelated to app keys. :) Good luck!

Comment: i generated a key when a started building the app but i will try to generate a new one.

Comment: no i tried that still the same the log files doesnt help much it keep generating the same mistake.

Comment: Did you check your .env file to make sure it's actually set correctly?

Comment: Yes i did it was set ok.i dont know what else to do.I created a function with for loop and make a 100 $http get calls only 58 times completed.the other times i got 500 error code.

Comment: How long is the app key?

Comment: 32 characters and the encryption is set at 256

Comment: Alright. I'm afraid I have no idea what your problem is but at least it's not related to the application key.